# nested promises in js using spotify API

Tags: api, spotify, es6-promise

I want to access the tracks `prop` and all of it's internal props as well from an album. using the Spotify JS wrapper API.
I'm writing nested promises as suggested on the documentation:
https://github.com/JMPerez/spotify-web-api-js

```
return spotifyApi.getArtistAlbums(id, {limit: 20})
  .then(data => data.items.map( a => spotifyApi.getAlbum(a.id) ))
  .then(album => console.log(album) ) //resolves album but no access to .props
```

The problem is that `album.track` returns `undefined` and I cannot access the any values of `props` inside even though the promise is being resolved with success. I need to map over tracks again to extract some info.

Check image of console here:
[Promise resolved](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W0Lwj.jpg)

How can I have access to `.tracks`? or for that matter, any prop and and nested props inside the resolved value if chaining promises returns `undefined`?

Answer (score 0):

```
export const START_FETCH_ALBUM_TRACKS = 'START_FETCH_ALBUM_TRACKS'
export const startFetchAlbumTracks = id => dispatch => {
    dispatch( fetchAlbumTracks(id) )
    return spotifyApi.getArtistAlbums(id, {limit: 20})
      .then(data => Promise.all( data.items.map( a => spotifyApi.getAlbumTracks(a.id) ) ))
      .then(data => data.map(json => dispatch( receiveAlbumTracks(json) ) ) )

}
```

Hope this helps someone else, this code does solves the nesting and returning `json` for tracks